# get nvarchar argument from DB in DLL

Tags: c++, dll, sqlanywhere

In order to prepare for a SQL Anywhere 16 to SQL Anywhere 17 migration, I need to ensure all functions provided by a DLL will work with UTF-8.

Until now, the DB's StoredProcedures took varchar(x) as parameters and passed them to the DLL, which worked fine.

```
Procedure code:

create procedure dba.stp_DLLGetData
(
   in as_Input1         varchar(30),
   in as_Input2         nvarchar(12)
)
external name 'fnGetData@myDLL.dll'
language C_ESQL32
go
```

Input 1 is handled as previously with ANSI.
Input 2 is the part, which I can't get to work.

```
DLL code:

void GetData(an_extfn_api* extapi, void* arg_handle){
   int         iRc = 0;
   wstring     wstrInput1(L"");
   wstring     wstrInput2(L"");
   string      argTemp;
   wstring     wstrTemp;
   LPWSTR      pUnicodeString;

   //get wstrInput1
   if (iRc == 0){
      iRc = getArgumentVarchar(extapi, arg_handle, 1, &argTemp);
      if (iRc != 0){
         iRc = -1;
      }
      else{
         pUnicodeString = ConvertToUNICODE(argTemp.c_str());
         wstrInput1 = wstring(pUnicodeString);
         free(pUnicodeString);
         argTemp.clear();
      }
   }

   //get wstrInput2
   if (iRc == 0){
      iRc = getArgumentNvarchar(extapi, arg_handle, 2, &wstrInput2);
      if (iRc != 0){
         iRc = -1;
      }
   }
}

int getArgumentVarchar(an_extfn_api* extapi, void* arg_handle, int iArgNum, string* argString){
   short       params;
   unsigned    offset;
   an_extfn_value argument;

   params = extapi->get_value(arg_handle, iArgNum, &argument);
   if (params == 0 || argument.data == NULL){
      return 1;
   }
   if (argument.type != DT_VARCHAR){
      return -1;
   }
   argString->clear();
   offset = 0;
   for( ; params != 0; ){
      if (argument.data == NULL) break;
      argString->append((char *) argument.data, argument.piece_len);
      offset += argument.piece_len;
      if (argument.piece_len == 0) break;
      params = extapi->get_piece(arg_handle, iArgNum, &argument, offset);
   }
   return 0;
}

int getArgumentNvarchar(an_extfn_api* extapi, void* arg_handle, int iArgNum, wstring* argString){
   short       params;
   unsigned    offset;
   an_extfn_value argument;

   wchar_t*     bla;

   params = extapi->get_value(arg_handle, iArgNum, &argument);
   if (params == 0 || argument.data == NULL){
      return 1;
   }
   if (argument.type != DT_NVARCHAR){       //error 1
      return -1;
   }
   argString->clear();
   offset = 0;
   for( ; params != 0; ){
      if (argument.data == NULL) break;
      argString->append((wchar_t*) argument.data, argument.piece_len); //error2
      offset += argument.piece_len;
      if (argument.piece_len == 0) break;
      params = extapi->get_piece(arg_handle, iArgNum, &argument, offset);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

At first I thought "Hey, easy thing, swap datatypes and that's it.", but it turned out it's more complicated.
According to the DB's documentation, nvarchar in SQL should refer to DT_NVARCHAR in C.

```
-SQL-         |  -data type-    |    -sqldef.h C type-
VARCHAR       | DT_VARCHAR      | Character data, with specified length 
LONG VARCHAR  | DT_LONGVARCHAR  | Character data, with specified length
NVARCHAR      | DT_NVARCHAR     | UTF-8 character data, with specified length 
LONG NVARCHAR | DT_LONGNVARCHAR | UTF-8 character data, with specified length
```

While debugging (bot Input-parameters hold the string 'evo01') when I check for the argument's datatype (error1), argument.type's datatype is a DT_LONGVARCHAR instead of a DT_NVARCHAR.
"no problem" I thought, maybe the evaluation is somehow wrong.
If I omit the datatype check and continue, I only get gibberish after applying a wchar_t* to argument.data.
If I apply a char* to the same nvarchar argument.data I get instead 'evo01'.

Can someone point out, what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: update
As the DB keeps passing invalid content and I'm running out of ideas, I decided to use a workaround and pass the arguments via long binary.
Not the most favourable solution, but one that works flawlessly.

Comment: All types say "character data" rather than "wide character data", so what makes you think a wchar would be applicable? SQL Server may use UTF-16 internally for its nvarchar strings, but that doesn't mean sqldef.c does.

Comment: @MrLister My believe is that I need a wchar to be able to hold e.g. a japanese sign. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Yes. The encoding used is UTF-8, not UTF-16, so you will need `char`s rather than `wchar_t`s. Suppose you have a .sql file containing the text `N'ア'`, it will be stored as bytes `4E 27 E3 82 A2 27` and not as `4E 00 27 00 A2 30 27 00`. Hope this helps rather than confusing things further.

Comment: @MrLister Yeah, that helps rather than creates more confusion. So I tried using char.  
Thing is the parameter 'blibla²èア' results in 'blibla²è'.
Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you're using a font that doesn't contain the ア character.

Comment: @MrLister there is a Control-Elemtent (SUB, 1A) after the 'è', which isn't displayed here. Getting the feeling data isn't passed correctly from DB.